# What is argument "grad_outputs" in chainer's backward function

Tags: chainer

3 questions:

1. what is grad_outputs in chainer?
2. one example in chainer's function F.transpose, how to explain this backward code?

   def backward(self, inputs, grad_outputs):
       gy = grad_outputs[0]
       inv_axes = self.axes
       if self.axes:
           axes = tuple(ax % len(self.axes) for ax in self.axes)
           inv_axes = tuple(numpy.argsort(axes))
       gx = gy.transpose(inv_axes)
       return gx,
3. suppose I want implement self define function, but my inputs[0] and inputs[1] have different shape, in order to back propagation using differential chain rule, I have to write following code in `backward`:

   a, b = inputs
   gy = grad_outputs[0]
   return a * gy, b * gy
   **But, a and b is not same shape, and `a * gy` and `b * gy` maybe report error? shape doesn't match to multiply?**

Answer (score 0):

*This answer applies to chainer v2, *the `Function` class's internal behavior may change after chainer v3* to support differentiable backpropagation.

Back propagation proceeds from final layer to first layer to propagate its gradients in order to calculate gradient for each layer's parameters.

The function's `backward` function receives gradient of output, and need to calculate & return gradient of input.

1. `grad_outputs` is the gradient for this function's output, in array (`numpy` or `cupy`) form.
2. I believe the basic idea is, `F.transpose`'s differentiation is also just a transpose, so it is just returning the transpose of gradient of output, `gy`.
   However rigorously, `F.transpose`'s transpose order is specified when we forward the computation, this order is kept as `self.axes` and in it needs to be reverse ordered in backward computation. I guess `inv_axes` is the reversely ordered axes and it is used to calculate gradient of input, written as `gx`.
3. As you wrote, you can return gradient of inputs in tuple format like `return a * gy, b * gy`. Shape does not matter and it can be different for each function's input (as well as the return values of `backward`)

Comment: about answer 3: if shape are different in a and b, How can it multiply with same shape gy. a * gy, b * gy?

Comment: still don't know what the shape is gy ?

Comment: I don't know what kind of formula you want to implement, but at least you can get the shape of `a`, `b` and `gy` in `backward` function, and you can write your formula according to the shape (if the formula depends on the shape). These are just numpy array or cupy array so you can use broadcast too.

Comment: one more question: if w and x shape are different(like conv layer or other layer), thus dw and dx shape are different, how can we element-wise top-layer's dx multiply by the previous-layer's dw that affect the change of w of this previous layer.